# error: cannot find symbol java

Tags: java

How can I fix this issue that I am having... Here is my code that I worked on and I can't seem to get the output. I don't know why this is occurring, I mean just recently it worked fine and I was getting the output, but now I am getting this error everytime.

```
public static TimeCard processTimeCard(String data)
{
   String[] split = data.split(",");
   String employee = split[0];
   String project = split[1];
   double rate = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);

   String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                      "Wednesday", "Thursday",
                      "Friday", "Saturday"};

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Get number of hours for each day of the week
   for (int index = 0; index < days.length; index++)
   {
       System.out.println("How many hours on " + days[index] + ".");
       double hours = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
   }


   // Create a TimeCard object and return a reference to it.
   return new TimeCard(employee, project, rate);

}

class TimeCard
{
   // Instance Variables
   private String employeeName;
   private String project;
   private double rate;
   private double hours;

   //Class Variables
   private static int numCards = 0;
   private static final double OT_MULTIPLIER = 1.5;
   private static final int OT_LIMIT = 40;


   /**
   * Constructor 1
   */
   public TimeCard(String employeeName, String project, double rate)
   {
       this.employee = employeeName;
       this.project = project;
       this.rate = rate;
       this.hours = hours;
   }

   public String getEmployee()
   {
       return this.employee;
   }

   public String getProject()
   {
       return this.project;
   }

   public double getRate()
   {
    return this.rate;
   }
}
```

Error I get is

```
    error: cannot find symbol
    this.employee = employeeName;
                &&
    error: cannot find symbol
    return this.employee;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you are using wrong variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.employee = employeeName;
```

There is no instance member called `employee` in your class `TimeCard`. it is `employeeName`.

You should write

```
  this.employeeName= employeeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have updated the variable name from `employee` to `employeeName`

the code should be `this.employeeName = employeeName`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes:-

```
 public TimeCard(String employeeName, String project, double rate)
   {
       this.employeeName= employeeName; // there is no such variable "employee" in your class 
       this.project = project;
       this.rate = rate;
       this.hours = hours;
   }

   public String getEmployee()
   {
       return this.employeeName;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declare variable

```
private String employeeName;
```

But, you are using `this.employee` which is wrong.

You can use this below constructor :-

```
/**
   * Constructor 1
   */
   public TimeCard(String employeeName, String project, double rate)
   { 
       //this.employee = employeeName; //this is wrong
       this.employeeName = employeeName;
       this.project = project;
       this.rate = rate;
       this.hours = hours;
   }
```